# Selects com nodejs+mysql no lado do cliente

Tags: javascript, node.js

Sou novo em nodejs, sempre usei o php com mysql e estou migrando para o node mas tenho alguns problemas, 
fazer o node conectar no banco funciona perfeitamente porem não obtenho exito ao tentar executar direto pelo chrome me retorna o erro Net.createConnection is not a function, como não tenho tanto conhecimento não sei se preciso de um framework para gerenciar a aplicação de maneira que o navegador entenda os select's sem que de erro, para os require funcionar estou usando o browserify 
meu codigo js

```
 var $ = require('jquery');
 var mysql = require('mysql');

 var con = mysql.createConnection({
 host:'localhost',
 port:'0000',
 user:'root',
 password:'123456',
 database:'qualquer'
 });

con.connect(function(err) {
if (err) throw err;
 con.query("select * From qualquer.teste", function (err, result, 
fields) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(result);
});
connection.end();
});""
```

Comment: Mas você está tentando usar um [plugin de servidor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) no cliente? Não vai funcionar.

Comment: não estou, quero usar no serve para que o cliente possa executar quando eu rodar a aplicação

Comment: Entendi, você quer fazer servidor baseado em sessões igual a ASP e PHP, onde o cliente só passa uma requisição HTTP contendo o id de sessão. Já conhece o [Express](https://expressjs.com/pt-br/)

Comment: Sim nesse parâmetro que procuro, ouvir falar nele irei dar uma olhada melhor sobre ele recomendo algum site em especial ? ficarei muito grato

Comment: O link que lhe passei é o site oficial em português. Acredito que esse componente lhe sirva de ajuda [Express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há uma diferênça grande entre PHP e Node. O PHP dá a ilusão que podes correr comandos de MySql no lado do cliente porque o PHP pode ter uma mistura de HTML, MySql e PHP no mesmo ficheiro que parece ser servido ao browser. 
Mas isso é uma ilusão. Na verdade todo o código PHP e MySql corre no servidor e para o browser vai uma outra versão desse código, processado, sem PHP ou MySql. Ou seja o browser não tem (e nunca deve ter) acesso ao MySql diretamente.

O que precisas de fazer é criar rotas/urls onde o Node possa correr código e enviar de volta uma resposta. Nessas rotas que são chamadas quando navegas para uma página no servidor, ou quando envias um pedido ajax, podes passar dados para o servidor saber o que fazer. No PHP esses dados são disponibilizados no `$_GET` ou `$_POST`, no Node isso funciona de maneira diferente, mas também podes aceder a esse tipo de dados.

Tendo dito isso, vale a pena referir que no Node é boa ideia usar uma biblioteca para criar o servidor, senão vais ter de fazer muita coisa à mão que é complexo. Testa por exemplo a biblioteca express.js. Um exemplo usando express.js seria assim:

Exemplo de url pedido: `http://localhost:3000/user/2?lang=en`

Código exemplo no Node:

```js
app.get('/user/:id', function(req, res) {
  const userId = Number(req.params.id);
  con.query("SELECT username From users WHERE id=" + userId, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send('Something went wrong...');
    }
    const lang = req.query.lang;

    if (lang === 'en') res.send('The user name is ' + result.name);
    else res.send('O nome do utilizador é ' + result.name);
  });
});
```